# Electrum Wallet - Is it possible to specify inputs in new transaction?

Tags: electrum, coin-control

In my wallet, I have bitcoins belonging to three different addresses.  I want to send the bitcoins from one of those addresses elsewhere.

This is made easier, perhaps, by the fact that the balance of that one address arrived in a single transaction.

Is there any way for me to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the secondary click on a address and then the "Send from" option.

Comment: Thank you.  Someone on the forums recommended a slightly different solution.  "Freeze" all the other addresses, by right-clicking and freezing.

Your solution is even more straight forward.

(I never knew the secondary click menu was there!)

Comment: Not sure if they changed the text in the meantime, but currently it's `Spend from` and not `Send from`.